# Posting to WebAPI with ModelClass Object as Parameter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin, xamarin.forms

We have web api like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public CustomAuthenticateModel AuthenticateByUsername(LoginModel model)
{
    return employeeService.AuthenticateByUsername(model.Username, model.AdDomain, model.IsAdAuthentication);
}
```

In my PCL Project I am trying to access via:

```
try
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    LoginModel l = new LoginModel();
    l.Username = model.Email;
    response = await apiClient.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, l); // Exception is fired at this line
}
catch(exception etc){}
```

and every time I am getting exception like:

> ex = {System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Net.Http.FormattingUtilities' threw an exception. ---> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
>     at System.Runtime.Serialization.XsdDataContractExporte...

This is an existing project, all API consume Model Class object as parameter. what is the right way to do this? I am trying to use MVVM helper library for this project.

Comment: What is your apiClient? Do you use a library for this

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Serialize your object before making a request. Javascript Serializer should work as good as Newtonsoft serializer

```
 var jsonRequest = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(argument);
 var content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "text/json");

 //url is the api, l is your object that you are passing
 var response = await client.PostAsync(url, l);

 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
 {
    //R is your object type, in this case LoginModel
    result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<R>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
 }
```